# Why do I not need to free this memory?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks

I'm writing a Python C extension, and in the examples listed [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example), there is a snippet of code:

```
static PyObject * spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command)) return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}
```

According to the documentation for parsing a string with PyArg_ParseTuple, "You must not provide storage for the string itself; a pointer to an existing string is stored into the character pointer variable whose address you pass."  So how does Python know when the memory pointed to by "command" can be freed?  How is a memory leak not occurring?

Comment: Where does it say Python frees the memory itself? I'd assume you need to free it when you're done.

Comment: When it says "a pointer to an existing string" I'd assume PyArq_ParseTuple doesn't allocate memory. Not a safe assumption though, I'd check the documentation.

Comment: @delnan that's what I thought as well, but when I try to free the memory, I get *** glibc detected *** python: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001ef16dc ***

Comment: @Thiago In that case, if I kept running spam_system, wouldn't I eventually run out of memory?

Comment: Yes, as just answered there is no extra memory being allocated. The function returns a pointer to a previously allocated object (the args parameter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html) says this about the "s" format specifier to `PyArg_ParseTuple`:

> `s` (string or Unicode) [const char *]
>   Convert a Python string or Unicode object to a C pointer to a character string. You must not provide storage for the string itself; a pointer to an existing string is stored into the character pointer variable whose address you pass.

That means that the pointer is pointing to memory that Python itself is managing.

If you dig into the Python source (I'm using version 3.2) you'll find `PyArg_ParseTuple` in `Python/getargs.c`. If you trace the execution (a mark-I eyeball should be sufficient if you already know C) you'll get to `convertsimple` which handles some simple data type format strings (such as "s"). Then have a look at the `'s'` branch of the switch and you'll see this:

```
char **p = va_arg(*p_va, char **);
/* ... */
*p = PyBytes_AS_STRING(uarg);
```

And a little grepping will yield the definition of `PyBytes_AS_STRING`:

```
#define PyBytes_AS_STRING(op) (assert(PyBytes_Check(op)), \
                                (((PyBytesObject *)(op))->ob_sval))
```

So all this is really doing is handing you a pointer to a field, `ob_sval`, inside the Python object; Python is managing the memory for its internal objects.

So, you shouldn't free your `command` string because it ends up pointing into some of Python's internal data and Python itself is responsible for that memory. Hence the "hands off" warning in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @mu, I should've thought to dig through the source to figure it out

Comment: @Andrew: I suspected that it would come down to something like `PyBytes_AS_STRING`, I was mostly verifying my guess. Glad to be of assistance anyway.

Comment: When does Python actually go ahead and free the memory? Does it somehow know that we are in a function call and once the function returns it can free the memory?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I'd guess there's a garbage collection system for `PyBytesObject`.